# Hyphenation of the word "interferometer" in British English

Tags: british-english, hyphenation, syllables

How is the word "*interferometer*" correctly split at the end of a line in **British English**, i.e. what is the correct syllabification?

I found two contradicting syllabifications:

- "*in·ter·fer·om·e·ter*" in Merriam-Webster (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/interferometer)
- "*in·ter·fe·rom·e·ter*" in the American Heritage Dictionary (http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=interferometer).

Is there any authority for British English (possibly accessible online)?

**Background:** I am writing a scientific article using the typesetting programme LATEX with Babel for British English, which automatically carries out the word splitting at the end of lines. The word "interferometer" is split as

> We are using an interfer-
>
> ometer for our measurements.

which apparently follows Merriam-Webster (see above). However the referee of the article is the opinion that the word is "strangely cut".

Comment: The referee is right: "interfero-meter" it is. Generally when the prefix is truncated (*interfer/ence/* + *o* + *meter*), the *o* modifies the prefix, not the suffix. In cases where the prefix is the full word, the *o* is not part of the prefix but instead can be 'prepended' to the suffix.

Comment: Note also that a specific style guide may be applicable in your case.

Comment: This is a tricky word; ***interfero-meter*** is wrong. It violates the rule "never break a word after a short vowel in an accented syllable; ***interferom-eter*** is wrong: it violates the rule "always break a word at a morphene boundary. As far as I can tell, ***interfer-ometer*** violates no rules, and should be the preferred hyphenation.

Comment: @Kris: Where does that "rule" come from? It certainly doesn't overrule the *don't break after a short vowel in an accented syllable* rule in any hyphenation lists I've seen. For example, *param-eter* and *para-metric* are hyphenated the way they are because of their differing pronunciations.

Comment: Thank you for the replies and comments so far. I did some more investigation myself, unfortunately only adding further confusion. Apparently most **-meters** are hyphenated separating the _m_ from the _e_ consistently in the Merriam-Webster & American Heritage: e.g. **ba·rom·e·ter** (bə-rä-mə-tər), **psy·chrom·e·ter** (sī-krä-mə-tər), **ta·chom·e·ter** (ta-kä-mə-tər), **ther·mom·e·ter** (thə-mä-mə-tər). This actually makes me wonder what an "**eter**" is. Exceptions are **volt·me·ter**, **hec·to·me·ter**, **ki·lo·me·ter** (why not **ki·lom·e·ter**??).

Comment: @KoRoWa, that would be because of the rule Peter mentioned. Presumably, hyphenating _kilometer_ as **ki·lo·me·ter** also means indicates a pronunciation with the first syllable stressed (‘KILL a meter’), while hyphenating it **ki·lom·eter** would indicate second-syllable stress.

Answer (score 2):

This is a tricky word. Here are some arguments for and against various hyphenations.

> ***interfero-meter*** is wrong; It violates the rule "never break a word after a short vowel in an accented syllable".
>   ***interferom-eter*** is wrong; it violates the rule "always break a word at a morphene boundary".
>   ***interfe-rometer*** is wrong; it breaks up the "er", which constitute a phoneme in American English rhotic accents. It also breaks the above rule about morpheme boundaries.
>   ***interfer-ometer*** is wrong; it violates the maximal onset principle: "always break a srting of consonants at the leftmost possible spot that allow the following syllable to start with a consonant cluster that could start a word in English" (subject to being consistent with the first rule above.

The maximum onset principle is illustrated by the word ***mon-strous***. You can start a word with "str" but not "nstr",

If you think this is important, you can appeal to the editor and cite Merriam-Webster (or American Heritage), and probably get the referee overruled.

I would guess that the British hyphenation is ***in-ter-fe-rom-e-ter***. This certainly is the hyphenation if the morpheme boundary rule doesn't overrule some other rules.

Comment: Given that there appears to be no good single right answer, and that the work is not designed to be read aloud, I would tend to agree with the referee, and break on the morpheme boundary, despite rule 1 above.  An additional factor (which could go either way) is that many readers of a paper will not be native English speakers, personally I would rather confuse their pronunciation than their etymology.  I certainly wouldn't see this as an issue to fight the referee over!

Comment: Perhaps the best place is *inter-ferometer* but I'm not sure about your last "rule": there isn't much in the way of "a string of consonants".

Comment: @Andrew: The maximum onset principle, if you have just one consonant in between vowels, says that the consonant goes with the following syllable. I would say this is the least important of the rules, and thus *interfer-ometer* is the best hyphenation. *Interfero-meter* has the major disadvantage of suggesting the pronunciation *interfere-owe-meter,* and *interfe-rometer* has the major disadvantage of breaking up the morpheme *interfere*.

Comment: @Chris H: unconvent-ional hyp-henation can lead to a manus-cript being serio-usly hard to read. I learned this many years ago when one of my papers was typeset in Hungary. *Interfer-ometer* also preserves morpheme boundaries, and doesn't suggest an incorrect pronunciation.

Comment: @PeterShor, I agree completely, my comment was only in reference to cases where there isn't a clear convention.  On balance you've convinced me, though I wouldn't pronounce *interfer* as *interfere*, more to rhyme with *suffer*, so it is at odds with my (British) pronunciation as interfere-ometer.

Comment: The maximum onset principle is overruled so often by morphemic considerations that I would safely say it can be ignored in a case as problematic as ‘interferometer’. **In·ter·fer·ome·ter** seems least infelicitous to me, too. Or perhaps even better: **in·ter·ferome·ter**. That at least violates absolutely no rules and maintains morphological consistency entirely.